# VBA function not calling correctly

Tags: excel, excel-2016, vba

I have the following function which finds the last row in a worksheet and am trying to call it in my Sub Submit_data(). The sub doesn't seem to recognise it and so the message box returns 0. However, if I place the exact same code in a test sub with nothing else in it it works. Anyone have any idea why this would be? note: my submit data sub is longer so I have just included the the first portion where the error occurs.

```
Private Function lasrow() As Long
Worksheets("Data - Complete").Select
lasrow = Cells.Find(What:="*", _
After:=Range("A1"), _
LookAt:=xlPart, _
LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
MatchCase:=False).Row
End Function

Sub Submit_data()

Dim lRow As Long
Dim lCol As Long
Dim colName As Long
Dim resetrange As Range
Dim indicator As String
Dim Dire(1 To 6, 1 To 2) As String
Dim i As Integer
Dim lasrow As Long, lasCol As Long
Dim lro As Long


Dire(1, 1) = "B2": Dire(1, 2) = "D2"
Dire(2, 1) = "B3": Dire(2, 2) = "D3"
Dire(3, 1) = "B4": Dire(3, 2) = "D4"
Dire(4, 1) = "G7": Dire(4, 2) = "I7"
Dire(5, 1) = "G11": Dire(5, 2) = "I11"
Dire(6, 1) = "G13": Dire(6, 2) = "I13"

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

If IsEmpty(Range("I15")) = False Then
    lro = lasrow
    Worksheets("User").Select
    Range("I15").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Data - Complete").Select
    Cells(lro + 1, 5).Select 'problem with selecting column
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Worksheets("User").Select
    Range("I15").Select
    Selection.ClearContents
MsgBox ("lRow is " & lro)

End If
```

Comment: `lro = lasrow` and `MsgBox ("lRow is " & lRow)`? Typos? Use Option Explicit.

Comment: On what line is the error and what exactly is the error?

Comment: ah yes, thanks for the help, i have added option explicit now. This was just a problem as i changed some variable names before posting on here, but the problem with the function not calling still persists

Comment: You are declaring a variable with the same name as your function. Remove the `Dim lasrow As Long`.

Comment: There is a much simpler way to find the last row. If you know what column will get you the last row you can use something like this `lro = ActiveSheet.Cells(ActiveSheet.Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).row` Then you won't need a separate function. Which I'm not sure is actually finding the last row.

Comment: Hey Mike, so when calling the lasrow function the sub should pull through a number. So the line 'lro = lasrow' should set variable lro to something like 70 in my example. However this does not work, and so when the rest of the code executes it works with lro as if it were 0.

Comment: That's because lasrow is 0. Like @SJR says you are declaring a variable with the same name as your function so you are never calling the function.

Comment: Mike does 'LastRow = ActiveSheet.Cells(ActiveSheet.Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).row' account for blank cells? Sorry I am quite new to VBA

Comment: Yes, what it does is look for the last row that has data by going from the bottom up, not the top down.

Comment: Ah i ok i will use this instead thank you! And thank you guys, SJR you were correct, removing Dim lasrow As Long made it work!

Comment: Just as an FYI, if you use an `@` in front of a users name then it will send an alert to that user.

Comment: Also I suggest you read up on how to avoid Select.

Answer (score 0):

Just to sum things up:

To fix the problem you are having you need to remove the variable declaration that has the same name as your function.

To make it even simpler you can just remove the function and have your sub like this:

```
Sub Submit_data()

    Dim lRow As Long
    Dim lCol As Long
    Dim colName As Long
    Dim resetrange As Range
    Dim indicator As String
    Dim Dire(1 To 6, 1 To 2) As String
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim lasCol As Long
    Dim lro As Long


    Dire(1, 1) = "B2": Dire(1, 2) = "D2"
    Dire(2, 1) = "B3": Dire(2, 2) = "D3"
    Dire(3, 1) = "B4": Dire(3, 2) = "D4"
    Dire(4, 1) = "G7": Dire(4, 2) = "I7"
    Dire(5, 1) = "G11": Dire(5, 2) = "I11"
    Dire(6, 1) = "G13": Dire(6, 2) = "I13"

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    If IsEmpty(Range("I15")) = False Then
        'Change this so find the last row without the function
        'The "1" is telling it to look in column "A"
        'The ActiveSheet.Rows.Count is using the maximum number of possible rows as the row which is 1048576
        'So it is starting in A1048576 and going up till it finds the first non-empty row and returning that row number
        lro = ActiveSheet.Cells(ActiveSheet.Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).row
        Worksheets("User").Select
        Range("I15").Select
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        Selection.Copy
        Sheets("Data - Complete").Select
        Cells(lro + 1, 5).Select 'problem with selecting column
        ActiveSheet.Paste
        Worksheets("User").Select
        Range("I15").Select
        Selection.ClearContents
    MsgBox ("lRow is " & lro)

    End If
```

and you still don't need the lasrow variable with what is showing here.